# Unable to create lockable file - Laravel 8 & PHP 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck in a Laravel project, I've been using laravel a lot of years and never happened this.

I'm using Vagrant (as always) and only happens this with PHP 8, **with other projects with php 7.X doesn't happen.**

[image]

The USER and GROUP permisions are OK as always. I Ran `chmod -R 777 storage` and bootstrap/cache a lot of times.
I ran all cache:clear.

I don't know why it's happening this.

Anyone had problems with Laravel and PHP 8?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If you try to create that file manually, does it work? Also, what exactly has changed between the last working state and the broken one?

Comment: @NicoHaase The file exists, and if I run cache:clear it happens again with another file. This only happens with PHP8. (It's a new project, but I have another project with php8 and also had problems with storage permissions)

Comment: Try this one `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*`

Comment: And what has changed between the latest working state and the broken one? Please edit your question to contain all detail

Comment: @RizkyArlin no mate... I resolved some session and cache problems using database and Redis instead of the filesystem, but with storage still, fail. I think maybe it's with my homestead machine because I didn't see more people with the same problem. I will try Laravel valet and see if it works

Comment: for me, this problem happens in the production environment. I use sentry for error logging. My scheduled commands always logged this error, which driving me crazy because it sucks all the sentry quota

Comment: @MarcGarcia have you solved this issue ?

Comment: @JohnLobo I've changed Homestead for Laravel Valet, and it works. I ran the homestead for a long time, maybe there was something broken

Comment: No idea, I have Ubuntus in digital ocean and all works fine, but not in local homestead... Very weird

Comment: I have the same issue in production with laravel 8 and php 7.4. it is sporadic and indeed always temporarily fixed by the chmod per above but later recurs as somehow laravel creates a new cache dir owned by root. This is clearly a bug. Does anyone have a Permanent fix?

Comment: anyone got any solution?

Comment: @Daryl, have you tried creating a dir owned by root? Something is running as root there, a cronjob or someone with SSH access running service tasks there. PHP doesn't randomly create directories you can't create by normal means. This question lacks a [mcve]. There are too many pieces of the puzzle missing.

Comment: @MarcGarcia try giving user permission like sudo chown -R apache:apache project folder and for storage

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : why would i try to create a dir as root? there are no root logins allowed on the server. Laravel is trying to create a file in a subdir in storage, for example, storage/framework/cache/data/85/5f/855f92484c8c414d36c1b25cb24876e30229cbbf and failing. invariably the storage/framework/cache/data/85/5f dir is owned by root. there are no cron jobs or anything running as root on the server.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that if you tried to, you would find that you can't, as it should be. The theory that some of your code creates the dir by accident is therefore very unlikely. Since that is ruled out, let's think about other sources: `sudo`. Programs with the SUID bit set. Cronjobs or other programs (webserver, PHP FPM, logrotate etc) running as root. Deployment scripts running as root. A process running on a different machine if some networked filesystem is used. In any case, this smells like when logs are opened, they are created on demand and then owned by that user. First one wins!

Comment: Is the `chmod` function run both inside the vagrant box and where you refer the vagrant  folder to? it could be that vagrant permissions are giving you the errors. I had a similar problem with my vagrant directory.

Answer (score 13):

Can you please try with the given permission, as it should be on web server group www-data level as well?

Also, adding a link for your reference.

https://linuxhint.com/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel/

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Worked for me laravel 8 with docker. For windows user need to run like this `docker-compose exec php-apache chmod -R ug+rwx storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache`   
Here `php-apache` is docker server name for apache and you have to give full path present in docker volume.

Answer (score 5):

Please use the following commands:

1. Clear your project's cache

```sh
cd /home/vagrant/code/project_folder_name
sudo php artisan cache:clear
```

2. Give your folders proper permission

```
sudo chmod 775 /home/vagrant/code/project_folder_name
sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/code/project_folder_name
```

Hopefully, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran
php artisan cache:clear
and it worked

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem with the Laravel cache. I explain how we could address the problem using a few steps. The following steps we took:

First:
We checked the permission of the files placed in the Laravel cache directory at the path `/var/www/html/storage/framework/cache/data/`. When you `ll`, the following output is visible at first look:
`drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 10:32 03`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 10:04 07`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 May 14 10:31 24`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 10:21 27`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 10:21 31`
`drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 09:47 44`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 May 14 10:30 48`
As you can see above, a few files are owned by `root`. This is the root of the problem. When you configure a Laravel project, it is supposed that the `www-data` user creates all files. We must find the cause of files created by the root user.

Second:
We could find out that operating systems were executing a few commands and jobs under the root user. So, we needed a solution to modify the schedule table of the cron job manager and execute the jobs with the `www-data` user. We first opened the cron table with the `crontab -e` command to do this. Then, we modified the cron table file as follows:
`* * * * * root su -c "php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log" -s /bin/bash www-data` 
By doing the abovementioned, the cron jobs are executed by a bash belonging to the `www-data` user.

Third:
We had a few files created by the `root` user in our project. To ensure that no file is owned by it, we highly recommend running the following command before purging the Laravel cache at the project's root folder (e.g., html).
`chown -R www-data:www-data html`
It recursively changes the ownership of all files and grants it to the `www-data` user.

Fourth:
After doing all the first three steps, we needed to clear the Laravel cache. So, the cache files are purged and reconstructed. One may purge the Laravel cache with the `php artisan cache:clear` command. After doing these steps, the output would be something like the following with no file owned by `root`.
`drwxrwxr-x 52 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 13:46 ./`
`drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 15  2021 ../`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 13:03 01/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:53 0e/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:32 10/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:52 25/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:32 39/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:52 3a/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:12 3f/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 13:46 42/`
`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 11:59 44/`
`drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 12:52 4d/`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by providing owner permission to apache user:

```
chown -R apache:apache storage/framework
```

Answer (score 0):

use command
php artisan storage:link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue. What happens is that the system doesn't recognize the user www-data, and it creates a root file because it can't find this user. It is recommended to replace www-data with another user, such as apache, for example.

```
[program:api-horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/html/example.com/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=apache //instead of root
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=86400
```

Then restart supervisor