# Unable to create lockable file Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, laravel-9

> PHP version   : 8.0.27
>
> Laravel version   : 9.45.1

I'm create a laravel project and upload it into shared hosting server (cpanel). That server already have some my other running project also with different laravel versions. After upload use above mention version project itkeep getting this error

```
Unable to create lockable file: /home/xxxxxx/domain_name/storage
/framework/cache/data/a0/52/a052c710b70b9dc1cc66e7710af44867198f74e1. Please ensure you 
have permission to create files in this location.
```

If this error occurred all other laravel project on that server getting same error. Also can't going to change php version page on cpanel provide. That page also getting error message. I'm tired with solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270924/unable-to-create-lockable-file-laravel-8-php-8) given solution. But it only works for limited time. If I clear the cache today it works without error but next day it getting this error again. Is their any permanent solution for this?

Comment: Hi There! Do you have permission to `chown` the storage directory? You need to do something like the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/71467012/3693312

Comment: @Rager yes I'm done that but still same result.

Comment: @Tharindu Prabodhana, have you checked the r/w/x permissions on the storage directory? They should be 755. If they are not, execute them recursively.

Comment: @slaff.bg They are 775 is it ok?

Comment: One solution would be to move your cache to database driver. Remember cache files won't be deleted automatically. This will cause issues over time

Comment: @Tharindu Prabodhana, yes, they should be (755). Now remove the cache directory and run the application. You can remove all the content in the framework directory. It will be created automatically if the permissions are indeed 755. [rm -rf /home/xxxxxx/domain_name/storage
/framework/*]