# Microsoft Azure Build and deploy PHP app to Azure Web App: Laravel App - Unable to create lockable file

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

We have a Laravel PHP application and we have deployed with the Build and deploy PHP app to Azure Web App workflow.

we have used nginx.

Sometimes we are facing issues related to permissions please find the below detailed error:

> Unable to create lockable file:
> `/home/site/wwwroot/storage/framework/cache/data/5a/0f/5a0fce553c194ec423d77dd06617ff2720c4c5c6.`
> Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location.

So the solution is we need to give the permission and ownership using the below command:

```
chmod -R 775 /home/site/wwwroot/storage
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/site/wwwroot/storage
```

but after execution, nothing happened, and I was facing the same problem randomly.

Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 1):

> give the permission and ownership using the below command: chmod -R 775 /home/site/wwwroot/storage chown -R www-data:www-data /home/site/wwwroot/storage

- Firstly, check that the web server user (often `www-data` or `nginx`) has appropriate ownership of the directories. On Azure Web App, the web server user may have a different name.
- Remove the cache directory and run the application. You can remove all the content in the framework directory. It will be created automatically if the permissions are indeed 755.

Remember cache files won't be deleted automatically. This will cause issues over time.

- run the `Artisan cache clear` command.

If still the issue is not cleared please use the below cmd.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

This command sets the permissions to read, write, and execute (full permissions) for the `storage` directory and all its contents.

**Reference:**

1. [Unable to create lockable file.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/unable-to-create-lockable-file?page=1&replyId=776166)
2. [Unable to create lockable file Laravel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420893/unable-to-create-lockable-file-laravel)
3. [I resolved it by providing owner permission to apache user.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71467012/20238030)

Comment: I have already applied this thing but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I have followed this blog [Unable to create lockable file - Laravel 8 & PHP 8](https://www.solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-unable-to-create-lockable-file-laravel-8-php-8.657436/) which addressed the similar issue. Please check and let me know.